# PHP simple_html_dom echo order

Tags: php, html

im tryng to fetch alt value of img and its href link i have created this snippet but it is echoing link and then alt value how can i make it to echo alt value and then the link?

the `html`

```
 <div id="images"><div class="img-logo-big" style="width: 130px"><a class="url" href="http://link.com"><img src="http://host.com/images/image.jpg" alt="image name" /></a></div>
    <div class="img-logo-big" style="width: 130px"><a class="url" href="http://link.com"><img src="http://host.com/images/image.jpg" alt="image name" /></a></div>
    <div class="img-logo-big" style="width: 130px"><a class="url" href="http://link.com"><img src="http://host.com/images/image.jpg" alt="image name" /></a></div></div></div>
```

any my `PHP code`

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();  
$html = $html->load($page);
foreach($html->find('div[id=images],img[alt],a[class=url]') as $element) {
$g .="$element->alt\n  $element->href";
echo $g;
    }
```

why this code has not effect `$g .="$element->alt\n  $element->href";  ?`

Comment: you are just searching the elements and echoing those matched elements. why do you need the output in that order?

Comment: im saving them to a text file so it has to be first alt value and after that the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you want to iterate is the parent of the img and the a, which is always a `.img-logo-big`:

```
foreach($html->find('.img-logo-big') as $img){
  echo $img->find('img', 0)->alt . "\n";
  echo $img->find('a', 0)->href . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As you already getting the tags in the variable `$g`

do it like this you will get alt value and image value separately from those resultant tags

```
$g='<div id="images"><div class="img-logo-big" style="width: 130px"><a class="url" href="http://link.com"><img src="http://host.com/images/image.jpg" alt="image name" /></a></div>
    <div class="img-logo-big" style="width: 130px"><a class="url" href="http://link.com"><img src="http://host.com/images/image.jpg" alt="image name" /></a></div>
    <div class="img-logo-big" style="width: 130px"><a class="url" href="http://link.com"><img src="http://host.com/images/image.jpg" alt="image name" /></a></div></div></div>';

preg_match_all('/<a class="url" href=(.*?)>|<img (?:.*?) alt=(.*?)\/>/', $g, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_values(array_filter($matches[1])));
print_r(array_values(array_filter($matches[2])));
```

Comment: that gets the img src i need href link.

Comment: sorry i thought you need img src's. see my updated answer. it is working fine

Comment: hello i need answer from those who is down voted this?

i am getting href links and alt text fine